# Machine learning input relationships

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, feature-engineering

After learning about a few machine-learning models (NN, SVM, decision trees), I was wondering if these models are able to find inherent relationships when learning. For example, if I feed it two inputs A and B, but it is really A - B or the percent change from A to B that determines the output (but this relationship is unknown to me), would these models be able to pick up that relationship from just the A and B inputs? What about more complicated relationships?

Comment: Well i am not sure if i understand correctly what you are asking but i will give it a try. I understand that you have data and you split them in A and B. You want to know if you train with A what will happen if you test with B?

Comment: What I meant was, suppose in my dataset I have height and age as inputs, and income is what I am trying to predict. But suppose it is really (age * height) that predicts income, albeit a pretty simple relationship. Can a ML model find that relationship?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you are asking that; given there is a true underlying model, e.g. *y = f(A,B)*, will any of the above learners discover and return the mathematical form of that relationship. The answer is no. Although, something like a neural network is sometimes called a universal function approximator, it is often discarded in favor of a more explainable model, like a linear model. In that case, the mathematical form is known.

For what you are describing, the use of evolutionary algorithms (e.g. genetic programming) are often used to find mathematical relationships between input predictors and output response.

If you are only asking if they can find some complex hidden relationships, without necessarily revealing the mathematical form of the model, then I agree with bayerj-- Yes.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. But in that case, couldn't I just throw all of my raw inputs that I think could possibly affect the outcome into the model, and not worry at all about transforming or creating new inputs?

Comment: If you are referring to GP-- yes -- the library of operators can apply different transformations, but at some point, as you increase the number of inputs and depth and breadth of trees, it can become computationally intensive.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they can.

All these models have the so called "universal approximation" property: they can approximate any function up to arbitrary accuracy. Yet, that statement is not about finding the parameters, i.e. optimization. That is a problem which is left to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the models you described above can find this relationship. For regression purposes when you want to learn the regression function maybe you can do this with Bayesian machine learning using Gaussian Processes. These can be used for regression - classification now matter what form has the true regression function. You can check the monograph of C. E Rasmussen and C. K. I Williams which is available for free [online](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/)